# Logging in Java Spring using slf4j, log4j

Tags: spring

what is the meaning and purpose of line

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
```

in log4j property file below

```
> log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t
> %c{2}:%L - %m%n log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, that for all classes in package `org.springframework.beans.factory` the loglevel is debug .